# Delphi Form Designer doesn't undo changes

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, form-designer

In the Delphi Form Designer how do I undo changes. I press Ctrl + Z and nothing happens, I go to Edit -> Undo and it is grayed out.

Am I just missing something or does this just not work?

Also, if it does just not work, are there any plugins which I could install to fix it?

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2747

Comment: Undo/redo only works in the code editor. Adding it to the form designer has been a feature request for quite some time, as @Sertac's link indicates.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was reported in 2002 and hasn't been added.

Comment: But you can *undelete* components in the form designer using Ctrl+Z.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, but you can't undo positioning or alignment or property changes. In the Code Editor, you can undo/redo anything you've done previously, including after you've saved (with the proper options set).

Comment: You can still use the History tab to revert to a previous version of the DFM.

Comment: Isaac Asimov predicted this in 1964.  While mankind would rise to the challenges of self-driving cars, the Internet, and moon colonies, scientists of the future would likely still be struggling with the problem of `undo` in the Delphi IDE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I just missing something or does this just not work?

Nope, it just does not work. This feature has never been implemented.

Comment: 2015 xe10, still not implemented

Comment: @waza How's the multi-level undo in your app?

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this problem, this topic was re-opened in 2015 with a [new feature request](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13278) on the Embarcadero Quality Portal.  The request was closed within weeks with a resolution of **"Won't Fix"**, so not only does this feature not exist, Embarcadero has firmly now declared that they do not ever intend to provide this feature.